# move folder from one thunderbird to another, not profile

Tags: files-folders, move

I had to add a second profile to my Thunderbird and had to delete the original. Prior I backed it all up.

Now I want to copy the previous folders to the new profile, but not copy the old profile.
With Explorer I can see the backup files, can I copy them? If so, which files to where?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to copy all the files from the backup of your folder.

You should first create in Thunderbird the new folder, then copy the
backup files into this new folder. Do not create the folder via Explorer,
but only via Thunderbird.

Copy all the files, but not the folder itself.

Comment: which are the actual files, msl, sqlite (-wal.file, -shm.file, msf file, .....

Comment: I had a functioning thunderbird, but do to my host provider I had to change some of the configuration (had (owl) suffix). This left 2 profiles. The new profile wouldn't work until I deleted the original.   I did a save so I have all the files, now which ones need to be restored.

Comment: **All** the files which were in the original folder.